# Making numbers and variables on a bar chart to become a different font color

Tags: r, data-visualization, bar-chart

[image]

For a figure like this, how can I make the numbers on the y axis, and the letter descriptions on the x axis become a black font color? (The default color seems to be a faint darkish grey color). I know it sounds simple, but I couldnt find this anywhere online, and any code that I have used does not work.

I am using ggplot() + geom_col() approach to plot my figure.

I would appreciate any help on how to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colour of text using `theme()`, e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)

df <- data.frame(variables = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 values = c(3, 4, 1, 2))

zissou1_palette <- wes_palette(name = "Zissou1", 5)
wes <- c(zissou1_palette[4], zissou1_palette[3], 
         zissou1_palette[2], zissou1_palette[4])
  
ggplot(df, aes(x = variables, y = values, fill = variables)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes) +
  theme_grey(base_size = 18) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = variables, y = values, fill = variables)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes) +
  theme_grey(base_size = 18) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black"),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>